# In a regression to estimate propensity score, how can I build weights proportional to two different quantities?

Tags: propensity-scores, weights

I have a set of 88 people undergoing a treatment. My focus is on their contacts with a psychiatric service in the year before starting of the treatment, so I want an exact match wrt their previous history. I have thousands of patients in the pre-treatment period to use as controls, and the same patient may be used multiple times (since I use arbitrary index dates corresponding to start of the treatment for the treated): among them, I obviously discard all the ones with none of the combinations I can find among the treated. I intend to estimate Propensity Score (PS) and the point is: which weights should I use? Thus:

1) Proportionality with the number of treated with such combination is something I want, since it implies that possible observations with controls showing a combination not present in the treated group are automatically excluded from regression, as I did. Let's call such variable $X$.

2) To 1, I would add inverse proportionality with the number of controls with such combination, $Y$. Thus, we could say it's the ratio between the number of treated and of controls, $\frac{X}{Y}$, that I want as weight. 
Proportionality with such ratio indeed protects from the risk that combinations that are over-represented in the control group (wrt the treated one) may affect the propensity score too much (since patients with those characteristics will tend to have a probability very close to 0), by ensuring that PS is determined basing on the characteristics of each combination (by given the same importance to each of them).

3) I would use such weights for controls only, by leaving a weight of 1 to treated. Use of fixed weights for treated guarantees they all have the same importance in determining the PS, so they can all have the same chance to get a good balance (points 1-3 are all meant to prevent a poor balance).
With such weights equal to 1, due to the $\frac{X}{Y}$ weights of controls, I would have the same probability ($0.5$) to be in the treatment group for all combinations. But since I'll enforce an exact match on combination, I don't see a problem in excluding such variable from the PS regression.

**The problem is: as much as I don't want combinations that are over-represented in the control group to affect $PS$ too much, I don't want *patients* that are overrepresented in the set of possible controls to do so. Thus, I would also want my weights in the control group to be inversely proportional to the number of occurrences of that person ($n$).** I could then, in building $Y$,use not the sum of observations *per se*, but the number of observations weighted for the number of times that person appears. But in which way? If that person always appears with the same combination $k$ times, then I could clearly give each observation a $1/k$ weight, but what if they appear in more than one combination? Please also consider that I would like each patient to only appear once in the final dataset (so I think I should exclude patients that then start treatment, and select two controls per treated first, to then be able to keep one).

**EDIT 22/07/19**

My idea is: if there are $C$ combinations in the treatment group, let us call $N_{c1} (c=1, \dots , n)$ the number of individuals observed per each combination in the treatment group, and $N_{c2}$ the number per each combination in the control group. Since the condition to respect is:\begin{equation}\label{base}\sum_{i=1}^{N_{c2}}w_{ic}=N_{c1}\end{equation} if each observation in the same combination had the same weight, it would be: $w_{ic}=w_{c}=\frac{N_{c1}}{N_{c2}}$.

If some people appear more than once, now $w_ic$ varies not only basing on combination $c$, but also on its number of occurrences. How can we introduce proportionality wrt number of occurrences? Does it make sense create a variable $n$ for the number of occurrences of each individual $i$ in the combinations found in the treatment group to create an intermediate variable $W_i=\frac{1}{n_i}$ (equal to $1$ for observations occurring only once and converging to $0$ with number of occurrences) to give each observation in each combination weight equal to a constant multiplied by $W_i$: $w_{ic}=KW_{i}$? Or the weighting system based on number of occurrences should be different when the same person appears in different combinations?